# Javascript work only after few reload or after a force reload [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with a function in js. I have a map in my site (php and html) like that:

```
<img id="imgMap" src="<?php echo $vett['IMG'] ?>" style='max-width:100%; max-height:100%; padding-bottom: 10%' border="1" usemap="#Map"/>
if ($lcz == 100500) {  ?>
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
                <area shape="rect" coords="571,838,369,710" href="main.php?lcz=100501"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100501] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="901,830,674,718" href="main.php?lcz=100502"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100502] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="684,572,457,460" href="main.php?lcz=100503"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100503] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="878,427,651,315" href="main.php?lcz=100504"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100504] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="1020,651,908,547" href="main.php?lcz=100505"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100505] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="1219,897,1107,793" href="main.php?lcz=100506"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo $vett[100506] ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="1475,769,1363,665" href="main.php?lcz=100507"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo addslashes($vett[100507]) ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="1214,593,1102,489" href="main.php?lcz=100508"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo addslashes($vett[100508]) ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
                <area shape="rect" coords="1451,309,1193,188" href="main.php?lcz=100509"
                      onmousemove="showToolTip(event,'<?php echo addslashes($vett[100509]) ?>');return false"
                      onmouseout="hideToolTip()"/>
            </map>
            <?php
        } ?>
```

And I have a function for resize map when map's image was resized.

```
var ImageMap = function (map) {
                              
                              var n,
                              areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                              len = areas.length,
                              coords = [],
                              previousWidth = document.getElementById('imgMap').naturalWidth;
                              for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                                    coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
                              }
                              this.resize = function () {
                              var n, m, clen,
                                    x = document.getElementById('imgMap').width / previousWidth;
                              for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                                    clen = coords[n].length;
                                    for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                                          coords[n][m] *= x;
                                    }
                                    areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                              }
                              previousWidth = document.getElementById('imgMap').width;
                              return true;
                              };
                              window.onresize = this.resize;
                        };
                  imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('Map'));
                  imageMap.resize();
```

The problem is everytime i load for the first time the map, the coords in map go to "NaN".
The only way to make it work is refresh page 1/2/3 times.

I found that solution:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('area')[0].coords == "NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN"){
                        location.reload(true);
                  }
```

but this is a really forced solution.

**EDIT:**

Main call that file from a jQuery load(). I tried to add the script in load like that (in test js there is the class ImageMap):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery('#down').load('islands.php', {
                            lcz: '<?php echo $lcz ?>', op: '2'
                        }, function(){
                                var imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('Map'));
                                imageMap.resize();
                        });
```

That solution didnt work, on the first load all coords went to "NaN".

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to log all variables in my function and.... if I log areas[0].coords (or areas[0].coords.split(',')) I have the right result, but if I log only areas all coords was NaN.

```
console.log(map.getElementsByTagName('area')[3].coords);
  console.log(areas[0].coords);
  console.log(areas[0].coords.split(','));
  console.log(areas);
```

**SOLVED**
Added to my JS:

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
          //My JS function
    }
img.src = '<?php echo $vett['IMG']; ?>';
```

Comment: wrap your js in a document ready, so it can be sure the elements are loaded and rendered before trying to "do anything" with them. Also, are you sure you are opening php in the top if() statement with a <?php   I didnt see one.

Comment: window.onload and document ready didn't work. I tried it

Comment: using jquery or vanilla?   here is vanilla https://www.codeinwp.com/snippets/jquery-document-ready-in-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: also just to verify ($lcz == 100500) on the initial page load right?

Comment: Added some information. I tried vanilla DOM but didnt work